# Unexpected Character(m~) In $SkipToken

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using ms graph api for java. At the beginning of the skipToken i have received inside @odata.nextLink, there is an unexpected character (m~) before actual skip token string (Can be seen below). Skip token string works fine after i get rid of m~.

But i am confused why this has happened and can other unexpected characters effect skipToken in the future? And what can i do to prevent that?

I am using msgraph java sdk version 2.4.0.

```
       https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=givenName%2csurname%2cuserPrincipalName%2cbusinessPhones%2cassignedPlans&$count=true&$orderby=displayName&$filter=&$top=2&$skiptoken=m~X%270100B7013B3B33303030343530303330303033323030333030303435303033313030343130303330303034353030333230303331303033303030343530303334303033383030333030303435303033323030333130303330303033373030333030303332303033303030343530303431303033323030333030303435303033303030333230303330303034353030333730303330303033303030343530303330303034313030333030303435303033323030333130303B313B303B%27
```

Comment: After trying to send the request with skiptoken starting with m~ i was able to retrieve next set of users. But still why did the format change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear how did you get the `m~` in skiptoken, but I can get the pages of users success by microsoft graph api sdk for java with below code:

```
package com.graph;

import java.util.List;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionPage;

public class Testgraph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("clientId")
                .clientSecret("clientSecret")
                .tenantId("tenantId")
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(clientSecretCredential);

        final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
            .buildClient();

        //You can use the code below to get current page users
        UserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();
        List<User> userList=users.getCurrentPage();
        for (User user:userList) {
            System.out.println(user.displayName);
        }
        
        //If you want to get nextpage, you can use below code
        UserCollectionPage users1 = users.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
        List<User> userList1=users1.getCurrentPage();
        for (User user:userList1) {
            System.out.println(user.displayName);
        }
    }

}
```